# Programatic product creation is failing

Tags: magento-1.7, dataflow, bundled-product

I have this simple function for creating simple products in my dataflow adapter class but this not working and throwing the errors while saving the products actully this function is creating the simple product attached with a bundle product which the adaper class another method is creating.

```
private function creatSimpleProduct($item,$importData,$skuid){
    /*creating a simple product*/

        $simple = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');    
            $item_arr = explode('+$',$item);
            $item_name = trim($item_arr[0]);
            $item_price = trim($item_arr[1]);

            $p = array(
                'sku' =>$importData['sku'].'-'.$skuid,
                'name' =>htmlentities($item_name),
                'description' =>htmlentities($item_name),
                'short_description' =>htmlentities($item_name),
                'type_id' => 'simple',
                'attribute_set_id' =>4,
                'weight' =>$importData['weight'],
                'visibility'=>1,
                'status'=>1,
                'created_at' => strtotime('now'),
                'store_id' =>1,
                'website_ids' =>array(1),
                'tax_class_id'=>2,
                'enable_googlecheckout'=>1,
                'price'=>$item_price,
                'cost'=>$item_price
            );

        $simple->setData($p);
        $simple->setStockData(array(
            'is_in_stock' => 1,
            'qty' =>$importData['qty']
        ));
        try {
            $simple->save();
        }
        catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
            $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__ ('Cannot save the product');
            Mage::throwException($message);
        }

        return $simple->getId();
  }
```

Any body having any idea about what i had made wrong?

Comment: I don't understand this. What do you try, what works and what does not work? :-)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt i code this fucntion checked all the required fields are coming and set but not able to create the product.

Comment: What is the exception message? Honestly, I'd recommend you use Magento API instead of creating EAV using the models directly. Have a look at the models `catalog/product_api` and `catalog/product_api_v2`.

Answer (score 2):

As I see in your script the name and the price of the product are the same:

```
$item_name = trim($item_arr[0]);
$item_price = trim($item_arr[0]);
```

Could it be that this is the error? Maybe `$item_price` is not a numeric value. I'm just shooting in the dark here. Post the source data for your script.

Comment: Yes its was the mistake.. i updated it but still not workingg.. :'(

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check system and exception log files. Log files can shade some light on exact issue.

Well you can also try this code

**To create a new product**

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setSku('sku');
$product->setStatus(1);
$product->setAttributeSetId(4);
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setName('product name');
$product->setCategoryIds(1);
$product->setWeight(100); 
$product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1));
$product->setDescription('Full description here');
$product->setShortDescription('Short description here');
$product->setPrice(99.99);
$product->setTaxClassId(0); //for None 
$product->setVisibility(4); // for catalog search
$product->->setSpecialPrice(59.99);
$product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));
$product->setStockData(array(
    'is_in_stock' => 1,
    'qty' => 100
));
$product->save();
```

**To Update a product**

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $product->setSku('sku');
    $product->setStatus(1);
    $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
    $product->setTypeId('simple');
    $product->setName('product name');
    $product->setCategoryIds(1);
    $product->setWeight(100); 
    $product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1));
    $product->setDescription('Full description here');
    $product->setShortDescription('Short description here');
    $product->setPrice(99.99);
    $product->setTaxClassId(0); //for None 
    $product->setVisibility(4); // for catalog search
    $product->->setSpecialPrice(59.99);
    $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));
    $product->setStockData(array(
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        'qty' => 100
    ));
    $product->save();
```

If you are just writing a script to create product you can aslo go for [Magento API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.create.html)